# jQuery tabs return false;

Tags: jquery

Just a quick one, which is fustrating!

I have three tabs which just literally fade in and hide the other tab content. Very basic.

Just can't figure out how to stop the links sending the page to the top, not a massive problem but annoying.

Here is there jQuery.

```
<script>
     jQuery("#accounttab").live('click', function(){

        jQuery("#accounttab").css("border", "2px solid #009FE3");
        jQuery("#salestab").css("border", "2px solid white");
        jQuery("#delivertab").css("border", "2px solid white");

        jQuery("#tabtext1").fadeIn(200);
        jQuery("#tabtext2").hide();
        jQuery("#tabtext3").hide();
    return false;
    }); 

     jQuery("#salestab").live('click', function(){

        jQuery("#salestab").css("border", "2px solid #009FE3");
        jQuery("#accounttab").css("border", "2px solid white");
        jQuery("#delivertab").css("border", "2px solid white");

        jQuery("#tabtext1").hide();
        jQuery("#tabtext2").fadeIn(200);
        jQuery("#tabtext3").hide();

    return false;
    }); 

     jQuery("#delivertab").live('click', function(){

        jQuery("#delivertab").css("border", "2px solid #009FE3");
        jQuery("#accounttab").css("border", "2px solid white");
        jQuery("#salestab").css("border", "2px solid white");

        jQuery("#tabtext1").hide();
        jQuery("#tabtext2").hide();
        jQuery("#tabtext3").fadeIn(200);

    return false;
    });


</script>
```

any advice would be awesome

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, there's a [tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), all of your handlers are basically doing the same thing so they can be combined, you need to `preventDefault` when you click the link, and `$` is a shorthand for `jQuery`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could shorten your code like:

**html**

```
<a id="accounttab" class='actab' href="#">Test1</a>
<a id="salestab" class='sltab' href="#">Test2</a>
<a id="delivertab" class='dtab' href="#">Test3</a>

<br /><br/>
<div id="tabtext1" class='actab'>Div test 1</div>
<div id="tabtext2" class='sltab'>Div test 2</div>
<div id="tabtext3" class='dtab'>Div test 3</div>
```

**js**

```
var tabsArr = ['#accounttab', '#salestab', '#delivertab'];
var joined = tabsArr.join(", ");

$(joined).live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("div[class!='"+selectedClass+"']").css("border", "2px solid white").hide();
    $("div[class='"+selectedClass+"']").css("border", "2px solid #009FE3").fadeIn(200);    
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBpxA/4/)

Answer (score 1):

[***Working Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/nbrooks/ctnPS/)

HTML

```
<div id='parent'>
<a href='#' id='acounttab' class='tablink'> Account </a>
<a href='#' id='salestab' class='tablink'>Sales </a>
<a href='#' id='delivertab' class='tablink'>Deliver </a>
</div>
<div id='tabtext1'>Account - Here you go!</div>
<div id='tabtext2'>Sales - Here you go!</div>
<div id='tabtext3'>Deliver - Here you go!</div>​
```

CSS

```
div[id^="tabtext"] { display:none; }​
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('#parent').on('click', 'a.tablink', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).css("border", "2px solid #009FE3");
        $('a.tablink').not(this).css("border", "2px solid white");

        var i = $(this).index('a.tablink');
        var tab = $('#tabtext'+(i+1)).fadeIn(200);
        $('div[id^="tabtext"]').not(tab).hide();

        return false;
    });
});

​
```

Comment: Using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) requires at least jQuery 1.7, but there are alternatives if necessary